# Emmet for option HTML - Increase the number of value attribute and text content

Tags: html, emmet

Is there an Emmet abbreviation for HTML element option, where the goal is to display this:

```html
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -2):

it is possible to get this result with this abbreviation

```
<!-- option[value="$"]{$}*3 -->

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Comment: Please don't post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) of code.